# Phosphor glowing spots from back side of screen inside a vacuum chamber; how to model faint, multiple reflections?

Tags: modeling, reflection, emission

I want to reproduce some mysterious, faint reflections inside a piece of equipment that we see occasionally.

[Low energy electron diffraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-energy_electron_diffraction) (LEED) systems have a back surface phosphor-coated screen like an old oscilloscope except that the glass is a section of a sphere rather than flat plate, and it sits inside a vacuum chamber so there's a second glass vacuum window in front of it. There are some shiny reflective metal cylindrical sections inside and I think that there are triple (or more) reflection paths between these surfaces that are causing faint ghost-like spots in addition to the bright spots we expect.

I've started to build something simple in Blender but I realize that I should think carefully about how I model the light sources. I want to make little circular patches of isotropically glowing material roughly 0.1 or 0.2 cm in diameter (see scale in my drawing below, I'm using 1 blender unit = 1 cm) on the back side of the glass screen, but:

1. How can I "paint" equal-sized circular glowing patches accurately on an icosphere surface with a subsurface modifier? I only care about the light going forward (phosphor layer is opaque) so maybe I can just make the glass thicker and embed the source inside it?
2. How should I think/worry about light going backwards; will the patches only radiate from one side? Will my cylindrical mirror be reflective on the *inside* automatically?

Right now I just make a glass sphere and put point lights inside it, then add a black plane to prevent any light getting into most of the glass sphere behind it, but I have a hunch there's a much better Blender way to do this.

[image: 0th order attempt at simulating a LEED system] [image: 0th order attempt at simulating a LEED system]

[image: LEED system very simple model]

---

#### For reference only:

This is from [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Si100Reconstructed.png) and gives a good visual impression, but the system I'm modeling is a little different and has additional cylindrical reflective surfaces inside that are probably the source of the faint multiple reflections.

[image: LEED system from Wikimedia]